# Codeignitier session outside application folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session

I have website where i need to use wordpress for single page because i need some plugin from wordpress.

Only problem i have is to call $_SESSION['email'] from wordpress even i set it inside codeignitier model.

```
public_html
application
  model
    User_Model.php
wordpress
  wp-content
    themes
      twentyfourteen
        header.php
```

So i want from header.php call session what is defined in User_Model.php by

```
   $newdata = array(
      'email'    => $rows->user_email,
      'logged_in'  => TRUE,
    );
   }
   $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
   $_SESSION['email'] = $newdata['email'];
   $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $newdata['logged_in'];
```

Can i somehow get userdata or $_SESSION variable outside ci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't get $_SESSION variable as ci outside the codeignitier. But if you just want to use php $_SESSION variable then you can use it like below.

First check on your file that SESSION is started or not if not then first start SESSION then get the $_SESSION data like below.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

Comment: Thanks you, you remind me for session_start(), i forgot it.

Comment: @DocNet  It's ok if this helpfull for you then can you please approve my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter doesn’t use standard PHP sessions, instead it saves session-data directly in a browser cookie, so it is not possible to use CI session outside of the application.

However there is a [native sessison library](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/using-native-php-sessions-with-codeigniter/) for codeigniter which  uses the standard PHP sessions so they are avaliable outside of your application.

that way if you do

```
$this->load->library( 'nativesession' );
$this->nativesession->set( 'cart', $cart );  //this will set the session
```

and ouside CI you can do

```
$_SESSION['cart']
```